# Datepicker from and to startDate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Date pick "from" and "to" work for the first time, but when I change the date "from", the date "to" is not working.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<th>From: <input type="text" class="from span2" value="" id="from"></th>
<th>To: <input type="text" class="to span2" value="" id="to"></th>
```

Script

```
var from = $('.from').datepicker({autoclose: true}).on('changeDate', function(e){           

    $('.to').datepicker({autoclose: true, startDate: e.date })

});
```

Here's my code http://jsfiddle.net/britonet/VS2zS/2/
First try it works perfect, I choose FROM = 07/03/2013, and Date TO disabled 07/02/2013, 07/01/2013.. and so on... but again if i change date FROM = 06/10/2013, it did not disabled Date TO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `$('.to').datepicker` is not initialized.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xNeTe/15/) is very simple fiddle to set **from** and **to** date ranges.

Updating for new :

Following code sets new start date :

```
var from = $('.from').datepicker({ autoclose: true }).on('changeDate', function(e){
$('.to').datepicker({ autoclose: true}).datepicker('setStartDate', e.date).focus();
});
```

[FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/injulkarnilesh/VS2zS/3/)

Comment: I'm using eternicode datepicker.js here's the link http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: Nils your example is a Jquery UI example, but the question was a bootstrap datepicker startDate question!

Comment: @Nils: I understand that this post is old, the external resources on the Fiddle are broken. Here's an updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/VS2zS/48/

Answer (score 0):

your **.to** should be outside your onchange. something like this,

```
var from = $('.from').datepicker({autoclose: true}).on('changeDate', function(e){           

});    

var to $('.to').datepicker({autoclose: true, startDate: e.date });
```

here is working code. the code will set the **starDate** to todays date. and the **endDate** will start **a day after startDate**. If startDate is changed, it will dynamically change the enddate, this way users can't select a date before startDate

the HTML:

```
From: <input type="text" class="from span2" value="" id="from"></th>
To: <input type="text" class="to span2" value="" id="to">
```

The JQuery:

```
var _startDate = new Date(); //todays date
var _endDate = new Date(_startDate.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); //plus 1 day
$('#from').datepicker({
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: _startDate,
  todayHighlight: true
}).on('changeDate', function(e){
    _endDate = new Date(e.date.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); //get new end date
    $('#to').datepicker('setStartDate', _endDate).focus(); //dynamically set new start date for #to
    });

$('#to').datepicker({
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: _endDate,
  todayHighlight: false
});
```

[HERE IS THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvb3K/6/)

For more information on [Eternicode's bootstrap datepicker, click here](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Comment: im using the other bootstrap-datepicker.js by eternicode, here's the link http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/. I think both of them are different datepicker

Comment: IF "FROM" = 07/26/2013, date "TO" should be disabled earliest date based on from. sorry for my bad english

Comment: `_startDate = new Date();` gives you the current date

Comment: The choosen date "FROM" to start in "TO". example whould be if FROM= 07/03/2013, Date "TO" should be 07/04/2013 or 07/05/2013..and so on NOT 07/02/2013....

Comment: first try works perfect, but on the second try when i choose another date "from" date "to" did not disabled. here's my code http://jsfiddle.net/britonet/VS2zS/2/

Comment: I should choose any date FROM. and date TO should start on what is choosen in date FROM

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize both datepickers and change the start date for the second one after picking a date in the first one:

```
var to = $('.to').datepicker({ autoclose: true });
var from = $('.from').datepicker({ autoclose: true }).on('changeDate', function(e){
    to.startDate = e.date;
});
```

Comment: it didn't disable earliest date "to"

Comment: sorry raidri, but it didn't disabled. here's my code. http://jsfiddle.net/britonet/VS2zS/